# NodeJS, fs.copyFileSync not working and not throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm using the nodeJS class fs for copying files from a folder to another, using a loop. The problem is that this function doesn't work. It's blocking on "fs.copyFileSync" but this is not throwing error

```
for(var i=0; i<pdf.length; i++) {

    console.log('STEP 1');

    //vmsy03/s$/Commesse/115400_BREBEMI/Opere/CE010/Report/CE010_Anomalie_2018.pdf
    var pathSource = pdf[i].path;

    console.log('STEP 2');

    //C:\Users\AFFATI~1\AppData\Local\Temp/SIOS4/CE010_RapportoIspezione_2018rev0/evalDocument_0.pdf
    var pathDestination = info.files_data.path.base + "/evalDocument_" + i + ".pdf";

    console.log('STEP 3');


    fs.copyFile(pathSource, pathDestination, (err) => {

        console.log('STEP 4');

        if (err) { 
            console.log('error ' + err);
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(pathSource + ' was copied to ' + pathDestination);
    });

    console.log('STEP 5');


    info.files_data.files.push(pathDestination);
    info.visualEvalDoc["controlDocTitle" + i] = pdf[i].docTitle;        

    console.log('STEP 6');
}
```

I don't know why it's blocking, any suggestion?

EDIT: node version: 4.4.6 
And this is the logging situation (I also edited the function with all the log)

[image]

Comment: so what error is it throwing actually ?

Comment: Nothing, that's the problem...it just blocks the function (i logged just before the copyFileSync and just after, and its logging just the first one)

Comment: try console logging `pathSource` and `pathDestination` to see if it points to the wright place. Also, have you included the necessary `modules` ? Such as `const fs = require('fs');`

Comment: Yes i already logged pathSource and pathDestination (the comment above those 2 variables are the result of the console.log)...and yes i added the correct module const fs = require('fs')...i used this in other part of the site and it's working, I don't know this time doesnt

Comment: try using `copyFile` instead of `copyFileSync`, tell me of that works. Also check your NodeJS versions if you have changed machines.

Comment: Still not working...no error, no log, nothing

Comment: check your `node version` if you changed machines. I find it highly unlikely that you are getting 0 output and logs. Console log everything

Comment: May be it is really waiting, does you open the file when copy?

Comment: @ZombieChowder I edited the post with the requested updates

Comment: @sinbar well...in another part of the site i use a function to open files as pdf inside the browser and its working, so i'm sure they are where i search for them (copying for a merge operation with a lot of pdf files, that's why im copying them inside a temp folder)

Comment: I'm really unsure at this point. Can you update your `nodejs` version, since you are using a really early one (4.0.6) ? Also check if it's a synchronous issue. Beyond that, I'm clueless, sorry.

Comment: I'm using node 4.4.6...but I cannot update, this is someone else's project and i just add some function, but i cannot touch modules, version and so on....i'll try to dig more, thanks anyway!

Comment: is the source a network share? can you give specifics?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty sorry? You mean to acces the project?

Comment: No no, the `var pathSource = pdf[i].path;`, are you accessing a network drive?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty ah sorry...yes i am accessing a shared drive...but i have permission to acces them, cause in another part of the site, i got the download button (access of file and download). So I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Yes, but you may need to escape tha slashes, so, `//vmsy03/s$/` this will be `////vmsy03//s$` and also replace the `/` with `\\` if this method doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197256/discussion-between-alesssz-and-aritra-chakraborty).